# asyncData get params of undefined

Tags: nuxt.js

first time the 'params' get '{}' in the editor, but chrome can get the true value, when i refresh the window, it 'console' the right value;

```
async asyncData({ store, params, query, route }) {
    const product = {};
    const slug = params.slug;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(route));
    const products = await api.product.all(store.state.locale);
    const currentProduct = products.find((item) => {
        return item.slug === slug;
    });}
```

Comment: create a reproduction on CSB